# How can i select and click SubMenu2 on mouse over MainMenu in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i select and click SubMenu2 on mouse over MainMenu in the menu given below?

- Menu

  - Sub Menu1
  - SubMenu2

I try with code given below but unable to select submenu2.Please help with your clues

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access > ul > li > a"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access > ul > li > ul > li > a"));
actions.moveToElement(subLink);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Comment: Since your subLink is actually link why don't you use LinkText method to find the element and then click on it?

Comment: Why did you placing mouse over submenu also?  Is it needed ? Just place the mouse on main menu and then click on submenu-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solutions as:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access  > ul > li:first-child> a"));

actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();

By submenucss= By.cssSelector(("#access> ul> li:first-child > ul>  li:last-child a"));

WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(submenucss));
WebElement submenu= driver.findElement(submenucss);
submenu.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

see your main menu is getting opened using mousehover function and for submenu you just need to click on the required link, so you don't need to perform mouseHover on submenu link.. .you can do something like below:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access > ul > li > a"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access > ul > li > ul > li > a"));
subLink.click();
```

This will solve your purpose.

Comment: and if you have multiple `<li>`'s or `<a>`'s?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable clue.However, i'm having problem to finding element in 

  WebElement subLink =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("nav#access ul li ul li a")). And got error message
       
        "Element is not currently visible".

  I even tried with
 
 WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("SubMenu2")); 
          <nav id="access">
 <ul>
 <li>
 <a href="#">Menu</a>
 <ul>
 <li>
 <a href="/SubMenu1">SubMenu1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="/SubMenu2">SubMenu2</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>

 </ul>
 </nav>       .What might be possible solutions.Please,share your ideas.

Comment: you don't want to use xpaths?

Comment: if not you can use this CSS selector to identify your 2 submenu
`nav#access :nth-child(2) > a`

Comment: Thanks for your repsponse. I no more have any problem with CssSelector but I am unable to select submenu2 However i am able to select main menu with code given below,

  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  WebElement menuHoverLink =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access > ul > li:first-child> a"));
  actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
  [PROBLEM LIES HERE SUBMENUS DONOT POPUP]
  WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#access> ul> li:first-child > ul> li:last-child a"));
  subLink.click();